# Distributing a Keras Model Across Multiple GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a very large Keras model and distribute it across multiple GPUs. To be clear I'm not trying to put multiple copies of the same model on multiple GPUs; I'm trying to put one large model across multiple GPUs. I've been using the multi_gpu_model function in Keras but based off a lot of the out of memory errors I've gotten while doing this it seems like it's just replicating the model rather than distributing it like I'd like.

I looked into Horovod but because I have a lot of windows specific logging tools running I'm hesitant to use it.

This seems to leave only tf.estimators for me to use. It's not clear from documentation though how I would use these estimators to do what I'm trying to do. For example which distribution strategy in 
tf.contrib.distribute would allow me to effectively batch out the model in the way I'm looking to do?

Is what I'm seeking to do with estimators possible and if so which strategy should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Estimator API. Convert your model using `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`

```
session_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
distribute = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(num_gpus=4)
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(train_distribute=distribute)
your_network = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model_fn=your_keras_model, config=run_config)
your_network.train(input_fn)
```

Don't forget to compile model

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with this because it's scalable and can be designed to adjust automatically to the number. Do you know of an easy way to generate the input_fn because that's where I'm currently stuck.

Comment: You can use tf.data.Dataset. First you create dataset object, than apply map func and batch your dataset. In the ens you return dataset object and use it in Estimator. You don't need to specify iterator. More on this here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets

Answer (score 0):

You can manually assign different parts of your Keras model to different GPUs using the TensorFlow backend. [This guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu) provides detailed examples and [this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/10/08/keras-vs-tensorflow-which-one-is-better-and-which-one-should-i-learn/) explains using Keras with TensorFlow.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
    #Create first part of your neural network

with tf.device("/device:GPU:1"):
    #Create second part of your neural network

#...

with tf.device("/device:GPU:n"):
    #Create nth part of your neural network
```

Beware: Communication delays between the CPU and multiple GPUs may add a substantial overhead to training.

Answer (score 0):

You need device parallelism. [This section](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#device-parallelism) of the Keras FAQ provides an example how to do this with Keras:

```
# Model where a shared LSTM is used to encode two different sequences in parallel
input_a = keras.Input(shape=(140, 256))
input_b = keras.Input(shape=(140, 256))

shared_lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(64)

# Process the first sequence on one GPU
with tf.device_scope('/gpu:0'):
    encoded_a = shared_lstm(tweet_a)
# Process the next sequence on another GPU
with tf.device_scope('/gpu:1'):
    encoded_b = shared_lstm(tweet_b)

# Concatenate results on CPU
with tf.device_scope('/cpu:0'):
    merged_vector = keras.layers.concatenate([encoded_a, encoded_b],
                                             axis=-1)
```